# Use a stub when running Azure Functions locally

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have an Azure Functions (.NET Core) project and I would like to select an implementation for some class depending on the environment. Something like the following:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddLogging();
        #if azure environment
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAzureApi, AzureApi>();
        #else
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAzureApi, AzureApiStub>();
        #endif
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to do this? Is it possible to configure such behavior local.settings.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to achieve this by using custom property in the config file.

```
 [FunctionName("CustomSettings")]
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var customSetting =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureEnvironment", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    if(customSetting == "Development")
    {
        //dosomething
    }
}
```

Add this property in the azure portal manually (AppSettings).
for more info -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/environment-variables?tabs=csharp 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#environment-variables

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DEBUG` preprocessor directive in your `Startup.cs` file:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAzureApi, AzureApiStub>();
#else
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAzureApi, AzureApi>();
#endif
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

You have to be running your solution in `Debug` configuration which I assume you would be doing when running locally?